# Transfer a large file/directory with SFTP via an intermediate SSH server

Tags: ssh, sftp

I want to transfer some data from another site. They have a SSH server through which I connect to that site.
Once connected, I use a SFTP command to an internal machine (which I cannot access directly from my machine) and get the data.

I now want to transfer a large bz2 file.

The problem is the SSH machine I use (to connect to the data) can ONLY hold around 50GB.

So this is what I do normally (below) but now I want to do it for transferring ALL the subfolders in this bz2 file VIA the SSH machine.

Current steps as follows:

```
ssh george@ssh.abc.com

sftp george@bigserver.abc.com

cd /temp/george

get file.txt

bye
exit
```

Now from my local machine:

```
sftp george@ssh.abc.com
get file.txt
bye
```

I also have a UNZIPPD folder in my data file if that helps.

What I want to do:

1) I want to transfer the whole folder to my local machine via the SSH server but as I mentioned the SSH server can only hold 50GB at a time.
I also want to do it that I can start it and not have to do it manually, file by file (like now).

2) Also don't want to lose the SSH/SFTP connection half way.

Any suggestions on scripts I could use would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [SFTP over double server hop](http://superuser.com/q/303486/213663).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` (in the openssh implementation, at least), allows you to set up port forwarding, when connecting:

```
ssh -L 4444:bigserver.abc.com:22 george@ssh.abc.com
```

which would locally open port 4444.

Now, connecting to localhost:4444 will actually be forwarded through your SSH tunnel:

sftp -P 4444 george@localhost

notice, however, that you must make twice as sure that the host keys match your expectation, as your local SSH will not expect bigserver's SSH key.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
rsync -PvL george@bigserver.abc.com:/temp/george/file.txt .
```

It uses ssh and also if the connection breaks you can rerun the command and continue from where you left

Answer (score 0):

1st - sftp has -r flag to get command to get directory recursively.

2nd - take a look on ssh forwarding, (i.e. flags -R and -L to ssh command). The idea is to use *ssh.abc.com* as a proxy. Try this as reference: http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html.

3rd - if you have tar on remote machine you may want create a tar on server targeting it to ssh connection and then untar on the local side of it.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/. May be useful with ssh tunneling.